# TinyMCE - how to add custom insert template button for each template

Tags: javascript, tinymce, zurb-foundation, tinymce-4

For keeping site responsiveness and applying standard grid system (I'm using Zurb Foundation) on custom user data entered on my web application I have defined some templates in tinyMCE to insert custom user data and pages on my web application. But it only includes one button in toolbar which is showing a dialog for selecting a template and pressing ok after it was selected.
This is the default button which is provided by templates plugin:

[image]

This is dialog which is shown:

[image]

But I need to define custom toolbar buttons to add my custom templates when user press them **without showing any dialog**. Is there any right way to do this on a simple way in tinyMCE without writing much of javascript codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to your comment

> without writing much of javascript codes

You will always have to write javascript to create something like this in TinyMce, but it doesn't have to be complicated. A simple and straightforward approach is to write a plugin for each toolbar button you would like to create.

For instance a plugin named "Insert template X" could be:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('test', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('test', {
        text: 'Test',
        icon: true,
        onclick: function() {
            editor.insertContent('This is inserted');
        }
    });
});
```

Find more information about building and using your own plugin's here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin

Comment: Thank you, is there any function in tinyMCE to insert contents from url? for example a function like .insertContentsFromFile(...)?